# Animation made using framer motion looks too lagged in reactjs

Tags: reactjs, animation, framer-motion

Here is the website [link](https://sadeedpv.github.io/Portfolio-website/#) and as you can see, the intro animations look too laggy. Here is the code:

```
<motion.div className='pic' initial={{x:window.innerWidth < 996?'0%':'100%'}} animate={{x:'0%'}} transition={{delay:'1.6', type:'spring'}}><img src={blob} alt='hero section image'></img></motion.div>
```

Even the animations after the hero section don't look nice. I have used the react-intersection-observer to activate the animation on scrolling in this particular code.

```
 <motion.div className='detailed' ref={refdetail} initial={{x:'100%', opacity:'0%'}} animate={{x: inViewdetail? '0%': '100%', opacity:inViewdetail? '100%': '0%'}} transition={{ delay:'1.5'}}>
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Recently I have worked with `framer.motion` and it worked well out in my side. 
I think that problem is related to the `delay` sub-prop you used in `transition` prop.

Here is my tested codebase with `motion.framer` which works fine in my side.

```
    <motion.div
      key={"setuplayout_motion"}
      exit={{ opacity: 0 }}
      initial={{ opacity: 0 }}
      animate={{ opacity: 1 }}
    >
      <SetupLayout setCurrentStep={setCurrentStep} />
    </motion.div>


    <motion.div
      animate={{
        x: authType === "sign-in" ? "10px" : "70px",
      }}
      transition={{
        x: { type: "spring", stiffness: 100 },
             duration: 0.8,
            delay: 0.2,
      }}
    />
```

Comment: It works fine when I animate the opacity, but when I change the position of elements on the viewport, it feels so laggy.

Comment: updated answer above